# AngularJS $watch multiple items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Watch 'Height','Chest','Waist','Hips' & 'Thigh' scopes, on change update $storage array.

**Current Problem:**
Although the below works, I'm having to repeat each section 5 times and feel this can be slimmed down and cleaned up!
I'm not 100% sure if this is the best way todo this and some reassurance and advice would be helpful!

Thank you.

```
  defaultStats();
  function defaultStats() {
    if ($scope.$storage.userData.bodyType === undefined) {
      $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
        {'height': 525,'chest': 32,'waist': 30,'hips': 34,'thighs': 20,'bodyType': bodyType}
      );
    }
    $scope.height = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.height;
    $scope.chest = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.chest;
    $scope.waist = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.waist;
    $scope.hips = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.hips;
    $scope.thighs = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.thighs;
  }
  var bodyType = 'triangle';
  $scope.$watch('height', function() {
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType}
    );
  });
  $scope.$watch('chest', function() {
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType}
    );
  });
  $scope.$watch('waist', function() {
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType}
    );
  });
  $scope.$watch('hips', function() {
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType}
    );
  });
  $scope.$watch('thighs', function() {
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType}
    );
  });
```

**Update**

```
  // Default Stats (Average UK Woman)
  defaultStats();
  function defaultStats() {
    if ($scope.$storage.userData.bodyType === undefined) {
      $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
        {'height': 525,'chest': 32,'waist': 30,'hips': 34,'thighs': 20,'bodyType': bodyType}
      );
    }
    $scope.height = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.height;
    $scope.chest = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.chest;
    $scope.waist = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.waist;
    $scope.hips = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.hips;
    $scope.thighs = $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType.thighs;
  }
  var bodyType = 'triangle';
  $scope.$watchGroup(['height', 'chest', 'waist', 'hips', 'thighs'], function() {
     $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = ({'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType});
  });
  // Reset Stats
  $scope.resetStats = function() {
    // Reset
    $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = (
      {'height': 525,'chest': 32,'waist': 30,'hips': 34,'thighs': 20, 'bodyType': ''}
    );
    defaultStats();
  };
```

Comment: you can use watchCollection

Comment: so what is the issue ? why dont you use watchCollection ?

Comment: @JayantPatil, I'll give this a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `$watchGroup`

So your watchers should look like

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['height', 'chest', 'waist', 'hips', 'thighs'], function() {
     $scope.$storage.userData.bodyType = ({'height': $scope.height,'chest': $scope.chest,'waist': $scope.waist,'hips': $scope.hips,'thighs': $scope.thighs,'bodyType': bodyType});
});
```

link to the documentation: [$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup)

Comment: this worked perfect, I've updated my script above! Would you be able to review and let me know if this the best possible way to achieve this!